Coupled Pendula Elastic Potential Energy
Suppose we have two pendula consisting of massless rods of length $b$ and point masses of mass $m$ at the end. Suppose further that the masses are connected by a spring of Hooke's constant $k$ which is un-stretched at equilibrium.
I want to write down the total potential energy of the system, which is that of gravity plus the elastic potential energy. The gravitational potential energy is easy enough to calculate. I'm having trouble with the elastic potential energy. Here is how I calculate it. Suppose the pendula are a distance $L$ apart at equilibrium. Then the positions of the masses are
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{r}_{1} = b\sin{(\theta_{1})}\hat{\imath} - b\cos{(\theta_{1})}\hat{\jmath}\\
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{r}_{2} = \left[L+b\sin{(\theta_{2})}\right]\hat{\imath} - b\cos{(\theta_{2})}\hat{\jmath}
\end{equation*}
in which $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ are the angular displacements from equilibrium of the masses. Then the distance between the masses is
\begin{equation*}
r^{2} = L^{2}+2b^{2}-2b^{2}\cos{(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})} - 2bL\sin{(\theta_{1})} + 2bL\sin{(\theta_{2})}.
\end{equation*}
Thus, the potential energy of the spring is
\begin{equation*}
V = \frac{1}{2}k(r-L)^{2}.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, the text I'm using (and a few other's I've checked) gives the elastic potential energy as
\begin{equation*}
V = \frac{1}{2}k\left[b\sin{(\theta_{1})}-b\sin{(\theta_{2})}\right]^{2}.
\end{equation*}
This makes sense if the spring is only allowed to stretch in the horizontal direction, but no such assumption is suggested in the phrasing of the example. How am I misunderstanding the system so that I get the incorrect elastic potential energy?
Edit: I see that there are two votes to close, and I would be grateful for advice on either how to make this question more appropriate for this forum or in what forum it would be more appropriately asked. This is a purely physical question... I don't understand the votes to close. If it matters, I'm not taking any classes or doing any homework. I'm self-learning.
Edit: Here is the accompanying illustration:

It is Example 12.4 on p. 488 of the $5^{\mathrm{th}}$ edition of Thornton and Marion's Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems. The same solution is obtained here. Neither place mentions the assumption that only horizontal displacements in the spring are to be considered. I wish they did mention it!
Edit: This question was closed because "Homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific computations instead of underlying physics concepts." This is unwarranted because I am sure of my work and I don't need help with computations. The underlying physics concept I want help understanding is elastic potential energy. Does it actually make conceptual, physical sense for the elastic potential energy to depend only upon the sine of the angular displacements. I can't see how that makes sense, and I need help.

The book is probably implicitly assuming small angles and thus ignoring any vertical displacements

I think I corrected my previous error and now calculate
$r^2 = (L - b\sin(\theta_1) + b\sin(\theta_2))^2 + b^2(\cos(\theta_1) - \cos(\theta_2))^2)$
which, with a bit of simplification in MAPLE software, is the equivalent of your equation above.
Now if we assume $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are small then $\cos(\theta_1) \approx \cos(\theta_2) \approx 1 $ and we simplify the above for $r$
$r = \sqrt{(L - b\sin(\theta_1) + b\sin(\theta_2))^2}$.
As you note, it is really $(r-L)^2$ that we want which, again with the help of MAPLE, simplifies to
$ (b \sin(\theta_2)-b\sin(\theta_1))^2$
which I think is equivalent to the equation in question.  So it's now clear to me, anyway, that the authors assume small angles and that the total stretch is assumed to be only in the horizontal direction.  This seems like a reasonable approximation, and you can see as much in the figure you drew.  In that case, I don't know why they don't just complete the usual assumption and take $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ as well.  Who knows.
PS I struggled with this more than necessary because I kept taking short cuts that weren't actually valid.

I hope it's a small-angle approximation that's the problem. I can't get the same answer you get for the change in spring length, but I'm not sure it matters.

Pretty sure some trig identities would equate the answers for small angles.  I'll try to confirm later.

Thank you for your explanation! I agree with your math as it relates to your pic. I'm sorry that I don't see how it relates to my question, though. The two pendula don't have the same equilibrium position. If they did, I'd agree with what you say.

If you rotate your reference axes so that pendulum 1 is vertical, the angle of pendulum 2 is now $\theta_2 - \theta_1$ and mass #1 is at the origin.  So it's easier to calculate the position of mass #2 and thus the spring displacement from equilibrium.  Just trying to confirm that the equation you quote is in fact simplified for small angles.

Right, but the fixed points of the pendula aren't at the same place--they're separated by a horizontal distance.

Yes, you know - I may have made a mistake.  I'm going to delete what I wrote above and re-check it later.  Sorry!

No worries! Thank you so much for your help!

I wanted to answer this question because it now makes sense to me, thanks largely to the discussion here. The compression of the spring from equilibrium is given by
\begin{align*}
s^{2} &= \left(r-L\right)^{2}\\
&= r^{2}+L^{2}-2rL\\
&= L^{2} + 2bL\left[\sin{(\theta_{2})}-\sin{(\theta_{1})}\right] + 2b^{2}  - 2b^{2}\cos{(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})} + L^{2}\cdots\\
&\hspace{1pc}\cdots - 2L\sqrt{L^{2} + 2bL\left[\sin{(\theta_{2})}-\sin{(\theta_{1})}\right] + 2b^{2}  - 2b^{2}\cos{(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})}}\\
&\approx b^{2}(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})^{2}
\end{align*}
where we have kept at most quadratic terms in the angular displacements. This is distinct from my (incorrect) supposition in my question statement that the compression is $r^{2}-L^{2}$. Therefore, the small-angle approximation to the elastic potential energy is
\begin{equation*}
V_{\mathrm{elast}}\approx \frac{1}{2}kb^{2}(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})^{2}.
\end{equation*}
Thus, in the small-angle approximation, my answer and the book's agree. It's a shame the book didn't really make any mention of the approximation being made, but it was fun to figure out, and that's how to learn.

I think that the book is making the assumption of small deviations from equilibrium, which would result in a predominantly horizontal displacement.
